# What is the right approach for calling fragment method from Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am using Pager Adapter and I want to call fragment method from activity. I tried with callback interface but I get null pointer exception because Fragment fragment = new Fragment() doesn't call onCreate() of that fragment. Any ideas how should I do this? This is my code:

MainActivity:

```
public interface Communicator {
    void passStatus(String status);
}

private Communicator communicator;

public void setCommunicator(Communicator communicator)
{
    this.communicator = communicator;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(communicator != null)
    {
        communicator.passStatus("STOP");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(communicator != null)
    {
        communicator.passStatus("START");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabBar);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    setCommunicator(new Communicator() {
        @Override
        public void passStatus(String status) {
            if(status == "START")
            {
                fragment.Start();
            }
            else if(status == "STOP")
            {
                fragment.Stop();
            }
        }
    });

    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(fragment, "Some fragment");
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(new AnotherFragment(), "Another fragment");
    
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedViewModel : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

You will create SharedViewModel in activity and export a LiveData for start or stop.
In your fragment, you will observer LiveData of SharedViewModel.

Class for one call event:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer

open class Event<out  T>(private val content: T) {

    @Suppress("MemberVisibilityCanBePrivate")
    var hasBeenHandled = false
        private set // Allow external read but not write

    /**
     * Returns the content and prevents its use again.
     */
    fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? {
        return if (hasBeenHandled) {
            null
        } else {
            hasBeenHandled = true
            content
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the content, even if it's already been handled.
     */
    fun peekContent(): T = content
}

class EventObserver<T>(private val onEventUnhandledContent: (T) -> Unit) : Observer<Event<T>> {
    override fun onChanged(event: Event<T>?) {
        event?.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let {
            onEventUnhandledContent(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use LiveData for 'one call events' you should create something like SingleLiveEvent instead.

Comment: I agree with you. I just give him an idea to resolve his issue. And as you said, we can use  the class that I updated in my answer for one call events.

Answer (score 0):

You can this, either by using ***SharedViewModel***, ***Interfaces callbacks***, ***Broadcast Receivers*** and also by using **getSupportFragmentManager**.

But the thing is that you will have to manage the things with null checks while accessing the views of the **Fragment** because in case if the **Fragment** is detached that will give a **NullPointerException**.